# Disabling memory overcommit on per-allocation basis

Tags: memory, allocation, memory-overcommitment

Is there a way to try to allocate a memory chunk and get an error if the memory is not instantly available?

calloc() seems like a good candidate as it touches the whole allocated memory immediately, however, I guess it will kill the process instead of returning NULL.

Any other options?

Comment: `calloc` won't necessarily touch all the memory, you'd have to do `malloc`+`memset` to do that (and yes, that may kill your process if overcommitted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No replies. I assume there is no way to disable application being OOM-killed because of a large allocation.